# Next Seo - file loader

Tags: next.js, seo

I am trying to integrate next-seo in _app.js.

I import the component into _app.js:

```
            import { NextSeo } from 'next-seo'
```

usage:

```
        <SiteLayout ctx={ctx}>
  <NextSeo
       "data"
    }}
  />
  <Component {...pageProps}  ctx={ctx} />
</SiteLayout>
```

I am receiving this error by console:

*error - ./node_modules/next-seo/lib/next-seo.module.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (210:23)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   }
|

> if (config.openGraph?.title || updatedTitle) {
> |     tagsToRender.push( /*#**PURE***/React.createElement("meta", {
> |       key: "og:title",*

Comment: `<NextSeo "data" }} />` isn't valid JSX syntax.

Comment: This was an example than inside the NextSeo component was my seo data